# Recovery can't mount system, cache, data, can't install anything

Tags: fastboot, unbricking, twrp, partitions

My internal partitions seem to be screwed up for some reason. Phone is a Zenfone 5. I'm not really sure how it got here but I wiped system, dalvik, cache, data, internal storage before so phone is completely empty. TWRP fails to mount /system, /cache, and /data and now I can't install any ROM, not even stock firmware. Sideloading also doesn't work.

[Here](http://pastebin.com/x5FBmpyU) is the log from TWRP when I try to install a new ROM.